# Drupal - Image Cache and Views for inline background images?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I have a View which is a series of images. I need the output of the View to be a div for each result with the image set as a background image with an inline style.

If i rewrite the output of the display as below, the divs are created but without any inline styles.

```
<div class="image-div" style="background-image:url('[field_image_fid]'); width: 250px"></div>
```

Note, its not that the styles are their but incorrect, they are completely stripped. From reading some posts I think this is a Drupal security measure, but I dont know how to turn it off. Apparently the Views Custom Fields module is a work around, but it seems to strip my fields also.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the field template for that field, check the theme information section under Basic Settings (D6) to see which template to use from the Views module directory.  Copy that file to your theme directory, make changes and save then rescan the template files in your view.

Comment: This is what ive done, but I was hoping (for the future) for a UI only solution. Is their one? Thanks

Comment: @jdln I would highly doubt it as it would introduce a hole in security and would be a big problem for the less knowledgeable users who would not understand the possible consequences